# Thread 1: Fatal error: Remainder of or division by zero

Tags: swift, fatal-error

I have problem, when I run my project I get a crash:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Remainder of or division by zero)

What does it mean? And what is the solution?

This my code:

```
let answer: String = data.ans // This variable called from SQLite database
answer.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "") // Delete spaces between words


let lenghtOfChar = answer as NSString
// char count
let width: Int = Int(view.frame.size.width) - 40
// frame width
var targetWidth: Int = (width - (lenghtOfChar.length - 1) * 5) / lenghtOfChar.length //Here's the crash !!!!!!!!!
```

What's the problem in my code?

Comment: What do you mean *"What does it mean"*? What is unclear about *"division by zero"*? You divide by `lenghtOfChar.length` which is `0` in your case apparently.

Comment: So what's the solution ?? I'm sure my `lengthOfChar.lenght` isn't 0 @luk2302

Comment: And I am pretty sure it *is* 0. Only one way to find out, you need to debug your code or add `print` statements to see what the length actually is.

Comment: I print my variable now and get me result (9) not zero! :) @luk2302

Comment: Assign lenghtOfChar.length to an int, and print that instead of your variable lenghtOfChar and let us know if it still isn’t zero.

Comment: Yes, it still isn’t zero. @Xartec

Comment: Based on the comment in the first answer as well as the error message you get it clearly is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the operation if the length is 0

```
let lenghtOfChar = (answer as NSString).length
guard lenghtOfChar != 0 else { return }
let width: Int = Int(view.frame.size.width) - 40
var targetWidth: Int = (width - (lenghtOfChar- 1) * 5)/lenghtOfChar
```

Alternatively, you could just set the width to 0 when your length is 0. Below is an example doing so with a turnery operator:

```
let lenghtOfChar = answer as NSString
let width: Int = Int(view.frame.size.width) - 40
var targetWidth: Int = lenghtOfChar.length == 0 ? 0 : (width - (lenghtOfChar.length - 1) * 5)/lenghtOfChar.length
```

Comment: You need to understand how `guard` statements work. Any code after the `guard ... {return}` wont be executed. So if you're adding your label *after* the guard statement, then that code will never be run when `lenghtOfChar == 0`

Comment: Ok so How can I remove crash and run my project and show my labels without white space text ?

Comment: I added a basic example on how to achieve what I think you want. But I strongly consider reading up on best practices in Swift at this point, because I believe that there are more than a few things present in your code that will make your life extremely unpleasant down the line.

Comment: Error (Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSString' and 'Int')

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Would you like to move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Sure. I've created a room called Help for developer1996

Comment: I can't to join to room due I must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here :(

Comment: So do you have twitter account or email ?